# Difference between using library project and Bit, in an Angular repo

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, reusability

For reusable code in angular, I use some regular angular libraries which include the whole common code (core and shared). It's built as npm packages and are installed in every consumer.

I've recently heard about **Angular Re-Usable Components Using Bit**.
https://bit.dev/

I Have question about it, maybe I am missing a fundamental understanding, so fix me if I have  mistakes.

Does the **Bit** replace the usability of a library?
Can I replace the current shared-module/core-module libraries to be managed by Bit ?